# List/Scale Node Pools using kubernetes-client java

Tags: list, kubernetes, scale, node-pools

Is there a way to scale/list node pools for a specific project ID using kubernetes-client java or kubernetes-client-extended libraries.?

I tried searching for APIs present inside kubernetes-client java library but didn't got any.

Link : https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using GKE then refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-pools) to add or manage the node pools or verify this [instance's methods](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/container/v1beta1/python/latest/container_v1beta1.projects.zones.clusters.nodePools.html) of creating a node pool, auto scaling the node pools.

You can also find more client libraries of kubernetes [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/).

**Edit 1**: seems to be there is no direct or generic library to list/scale node pools but in GKE we are having an option called  [resize Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) Standard clusters](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/resizing-a-cluster). You can resize a cluster to increase or decrease the number of nodes in that cluster.

You can also use GKE's [cluster autoscaler](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler) feature that automatically resizes your node pools in response to changing conditions, such as changes in your workloads and resource usage.

**Edit 2**: there is no native k8s library available to list or scale node pools.

You can raise your issue [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/#support)

These are the officially available [kubernetes client libraries](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/#officially-supported-kubernetes-client-libraries) and link  for [java client Library](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/)

Comment: I am looking for any library which will be tightly coupled to GKE. It will be better if you can point out me to any Kubernetes specific client which will help me to get/Scale node pools.

Comment: @PawanGorai : As per above comment tightly coupled to GKE you can refer edit1 and if you need native k8s only then i have updated the response in edit2.